# No rules found post PMD upgraded to PMD 6.48

Tags: apex, rules, pmd

```
SEVERE: Cannot load ruleset D:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\Devops\TestWarningNextGen/rule/apex/ruleset.xml: Cannot resolve rule/ruleset reference 'category/apex/codestyle.xml/ClassNamingConventions'.  Make sure the resource is a valid file or URL and is on the CLASSPATH. Use --debug (or a fine log level) to see the current classpath.
Sep 21, 2022 1:34:32 PM net.sourceforge.pmd.util.log.internal.SimpleMessageReporter logImpl
FINE: net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetNotFoundException: Cannot resolve rule/ruleset reference 'category/apex/codestyle.xml/ClassNamingConventions'.  Make sure the resource is a valid file or URL and is on the CLASSPATH. Use --debug (or a fine log level) to see the current classpath.
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetReferenceId.getInputStream(RuleSetReferenceId.java:440)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:361)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRule(RuleSetFactory.java:342)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:690)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:505)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetLoader.loadFromResource(RuleSetLoader.java:253)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetLoader.loadFromResource(RuleSetLoader.java:153)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetLoader.loadRuleSetsWithoutException(RuleSetLoader.java:203)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.PmdAnalysis.create(PmdAnalysis.java:122)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.PMD.doPMD(PMD.java:246)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.PMD.runPmd(PMD.java:504)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.PMD.runPmd(PMD.java:471)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.PMD.main(PMD.java:417)

Sep 21, 2022 1:34:32 PM net.sourceforge.pmd.util.log.internal.SimpleMessageReporter logImpl
WARNING: No rules found. Maybe you misspelled a rule name? (D:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\Devops\TestWarningNextGen/rule/apex/ruleset.xml)
+ exit 0
```

Comment: The rule reference (`category/apex/codestyle.xml/ClassNamingConventions`) looks ok - the rule is https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_apex_codestyle.html#classnamingconventions and should exist in PMD 6.48.0 as well.

How did you upgrade PMD? Maybe not all jar files have been updated correctly?

Comment: I downloaded the zip and extracted the contents at D:/PMD location and removed the older version PMD. Added common-lang3.jar as it was throwing error for this, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.

Comment: This is resolved after adding the jars in the CLASSPATH. D:\pmd-bin-6.50.0\lib\*